# Why Is it Impossible to Have a Noiseless Channel in Real Life

Tags: networking, tcp, channel, nyquist

I'm in the middle of a course on networking and communications. So far I found the physical layer of communication the most interesting. There's one thing that bothers me though. Why is it impossible to have a noiseless channel??

When the Nyquist channel capacity was discussed, it was emphasized strongly that no such thing as a noiseless channel actually exists. But isn't it possible to remove all sources of noise so that noise is pretty much negligible?

Comment: "Pretty much negligible" isn't "noiseless", just like 0.01 K isn't absolute zero.

Comment: That makes sense. So just like absolute 0, 0 noise cannot be achieved? What would be the typical source(s) of noise that cannot be eliminated?

Comment: Stuff like quantum mechanical uncertainty effects or the ever-present possibility that a construction worker will stick a backhoe through your cables. (That counts as noise.)